# WSO2 API Manager with separate, external Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Can WSO2 API Manager be used with a separate Identity Server as IdP, without sharing the database? All documentation and tutorials point to a special version of IS and sharing the database, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: If you need to use the identity server totally separated without sharing the user stores, you should configure IS as a federated idp.

Comment: @Menaka I've tried to do that (configuring service providers to use IS as federated IdP), but I can only login if I use "admin" user from IS, for other users I get "Error 403 : Forbidden

The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the requested resource."

Comment: What is the apim version that you are using?

Comment: @Menaka API-M 3.0.0 and IS 5.9.0

Comment: The forbidden error might be due to the insufficient roles of the user. Did you check whether that user has required roles to login to Publisher?

Comment: @VithursaM The users in external IS have the same roles as the admin user in API-M: Internal/subscriber, Application/admin_admin_publisher, Internal/creator, Application/admin_admin_store, Internal/publisher, Internal/analytics. These roles are returned via OIDC to the API-M. (I test with WSO2 OAuth Playground app.)

Comment: In order to login to the api publisher, try enabling role and user provisioning. You will have to map the idp role to internal apim role when provisioning the user.

Comment: @Menaka I configured inbound provisioning and users in IdP have the same role names as in API Manager (Internal/subscriber, Internal/publisher), but when the user logs in, roles are not provisioned (only username).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure WSO2 API Manager with an external IDP without using WSO2 IS. I think this [blog](https://medium.com/@shammijayasinghe/saml-sso-wso2-api-manager-and-keycloak-bd3eec6038b2) will be helpful for you. In this blog, [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) has been used as the federated IDP for SSO.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there part 2? I connected API-M and IS, but the roles for users are not provisioned on first login, so I can only use "admin" user from IS for API-M.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure IS as federated Identity Provider. This [blog](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/5-easy-step-to-configure-wso2-is-as-a-federated-saml-idp-in-is-km-or-apim-2d7505dff794) has steps to configure WSO2 IS as federated IdP for API Manager.

Comment: This tutorial also explains how to connect to external IS through IS-KM. Can I avoid additional IS as Key Manager instance and connect API Manager directly to external IS?

Comment: Yes, you can create the Identity Provider in API Manager (Step 3) and select Federated authentication as **Authentication Type** under **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration**.